# Can vimwiki be made to treat list indentation the way vim-notes does?

Tags: indentation, plugin-vimwiki

I've looked through the `vimwiki` documentation and a few questions here on SO, but don't see how I can manage this. In `vim-notes`, hitting `TAB` within a list indents the entire list item. In `vimwiki`, hitting `TAB` within a list indents within the list item, leaving the list marker unmoved.

For example, I have written one list item and hit `ENTER` to start a second. Both `vimwiki` and `vim-notes` treat this similarly: they both match the indentation and list marker of the preceding line. [Here `>---` is a `TAB` character, `*` is the list marker, and `|` is the curser position.]

```
1 >--- * My list item
2 >--- * |
```

If I'm using `vim-notes`, hitting `TAB` will achieve this:

```
1 >--- * My list item
2 >--- >--- * |
```

In `vimwiki`, hitting `TAB` will achieve this:

```
1 >--- * My list item
2 >--- * >---|
```

Obviously I can exit insert mode, navigate to the start of the line, hit `TAB`, then hit `A` to continue typing at the end of the line but that's not a good flow.

There is a setting, `g:notes_tab_indents`, that controls this behavior in `vim-notes`, but I haven't found a corresponding control for `vimwiki`. The closest reference I can find to the behavior `vimwiki` anticipates supporting is in `g:vimwiki_folding` where it discusses how `vimwiki` expects lists to be "nicely indented with `shiftwidth`":

```
*g:vimwiki_folding*

Enable/disable Vimwiki's folding (outline) functionality. Folding in
Vimwiki can uses either the 'expr' or the 'syntax' |foldmethod| of Vim.

Value           Description~

''              Disable folding    
'expr'          Folding based on expression (folds sections and code blocks)    
'syntax'        Folding based on syntax (folds sections; slower than 'expr')    
'list'          Folding based on expression (folds list subitems; much slower)    
'custom'        Leave the folding settings as they are (e.g. set by another
                plugin)

Default: ''

Limitations:    
  - Opening very large files may be slow when folding is enabled.    
  - 'list' folding is particularly slow with larger files.    
  - 'list' is intended to work with lists nicely indented with 'shiftwidth'.    
  - 'syntax' is only available for the default syntax so far.
```

The `shiftwidth` documentation describes functionality I'd never known about before: `<<` and `>>`. The former reduces the current line/selection's indent by one tab stop; the latter expands the indentation. This is obviously not available in insert mode, so not optimal, but it'll definitely do in a pinch (especially when I remap it).

I read through the `vim-notes` code and short of replicating the functions in my own (first) project, I'm not sure if there is some `vim` functionality, e.g., some keymapping, that can achieve at least the `TAB` indentation behavior (much of the relevant `vim-notes` functions use regex patterns to match bullet styles).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to ignore the majority of your question (perhaps someone will be along later to provide more specifically what you're asking for) and instead suggest that you just use insert mode's indent command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>.

`:help i_CTRL-T`:

> Insert one shiftwidth of indent at the start of the current line.  The indent is always rounded to a 'shiftwidth' (this is vi compatible).  {Vi: only when in indent}

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> for outdent.

**EDIT**: If you're dead set on indenting with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, a simple but inelegant method would be to map it:

```
:inoremap <tab> <c-t>
```

You'd presumably only want this to apply to vimwiki files, so add the command to a new file:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vimwiki.vim
```

This approach could of course be refined to only perform indent when appropriate, or to perform more intelligent indent. You could of course take a look at [vim-notes's indent function](https://github.com/xolox/vim-notes/blob/master/autoload/xolox/notes.vim#L1045) for ideas/implementation tips.

Comment: Holy smokes. This is very close to and perhaps exactly what I'm looking for. How I managed to do all that searching (including `/indent` while in `vim` help) and not find it is...something. I'll likely accept this as the answer but will play a little first. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielBlack See my edit for a quick fix.

Comment: Came here looking for the same thing as the OP and learned about <C-T> and <C-D> which I didn't know about before. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`gll` indents item right.

`glh` indents item left.

Comment: I guess this are mappings from `vimwiki`. You should add a little bit of context and perhaps what help tag to use to get more information.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Linking to the [relevant documentation](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/v2.4/doc/vimwiki.txt#L409-L414) and a bit of context can be useful for future readers :)

Comment: Only in normal mode. In editing mode <C-t> & <C-d> are the default keybindings.